# Why did my Print Widget stop working in Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, arcgis-enterprise, print-templates

I have a Web Mapping Application designed in Web AppBuilder Developer Edition for ArcGIS Enterprise.  The print widget uses a custom print service that, up until a couple weeks ago, was working just fine.  But now, when attempting to print from one of our templates, it either throws an error with no description as to what went wrong, or sits and sits like it's processing, but without generating the print.  Our print templates are on a network location which has a Data Store pointing to it.  That Data Store validates with no issue.  What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently, my company had this very issue which affected two separate applications, maintained by two different people, at the same time.  We could not print to any of our templates, however, using the "MAP_ONLY" template that's built-in to the widget, we succeeded in getting it to print.

This led us to start investigating the templates as the culprit.  First we updated the paths of any company logos in our maps to UNC paths.  That didn't fix the issue.  We have inset "overview" maps in all of our templates in both applications.  The data sources were part of Data Stores that validate successfully.  So initially we didn't think to do anything with them.  However, after nothing else seemed to work, we went back and removed these layers, saved the template .mxd file, and then attempted to print from the widget.  Printing started working.

Somehow, something must have changed in one or all of our basemap inset map layers.  Being that we hadn't changed our templates, we suspect it was either a vague change to the Data Store, to the Enterprise Geodatabase, or user credentials.  We were unable to pinpoint the exact thing that changed, however, the solution was as simple as:

- Remove the layers
- Save the template .mxd
- Close out of ArcMap[*]
- Reopen the template .mxd
- Adding the layers back in using a data source path that you know will validate in your site's Data Store.

[*] I have had issues in the past where closing out of ArcMap is necessary when replacing a layer in order to kill any stale connections to data sources.  Skipping this step seems to sometimes keep the old data connection around when adding the layer back in, as opposed to introducing the layer with a fresh data connection, especially when trying to re-source the data from a lettered drive path to UNC path.